# Bring data from Google Spreadsheet to Google Documents

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Is there anyway to read the data from a Google Spreadsheet (which I owh) to another Google Document, something like specifying a data source in MS Word?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, [this](http://techattitude.com/online-tools/embed-a-spreadsheet-into-google-docs/) is the closest you can get to actually embedding the spreadsheet.

You can't see the actual spreadsheet or edit it, but you can at least see the graphed data, which will be updated automatically if you make changes to the spreadsheet.